# How do I actually use the LinkerBindInputPaths PropertyGroup in a WiX Installer script

Tags: wix, wix3.7

I've got a WiX installer script that references files in a folder at the root of my Visual Studio Solution folder.  In my .wixproj, I've tried setting the `Properties` | `Tool Setting` | `Linker` to

```
-b $(SolutionDir)\WixSource
```

and get an error because within the middle of the $SolutionDir variable is a folder with a space. So, I tried

```
-b "$(SolutionDir)\WixSource"
```

and get an error complaining about using quotes around the name and that I should put a double backslash at, apparently, the end of the folder with spaces in it.  **--can't do that because it is inside the `$(SolutionDir)` macro.**

So, following a suggestion on SO, I looked toward trying to use the `LinkerBindInputPaths` PropertyGroup, but the documentation is severely lacking on actual usage of this property.

*I'm running WiX 3.7, and the following isn't allowed...*

While Googling, I was told to that it needs to go inside the `<Package>` element like:

```
<Package ...>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <LinkerBindInputPaths ???/>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Package>
```

The WiX documentation @ http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/msbuild_task_reference_light.htm says

**Specifies a binder path that the linker should use to locate all files. This is equivalent to the -b  switch in light.exe.
Named BindPaths are created by prefixing the 2-or-more-character bucket name followed by an equal sign ("=") to the supplied path.**

With no examples found from googling, I can't decipher what a '2-or-more-character bucket name' is, or if there are any rules around it.

I was hoping to be able to specify something like `$(var.SolutionDir)\WixSource`, but need some help identifying how to solve this problem...

Comment: FWIW, WiX isn't a "script". It'll be easier to learn if you put that myth aside.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LinkerBindInputPaths` is an item group, not a property group. It goes in your .wixproj MSBuild project file. For example:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <BindInputPaths Include="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)" />
  <BindInputPaths Include="$(WIX_ROOT)src" />
  <BindInputPaths Include="$(WIX_ROOT)bin" />
  <BindInputPaths Include="$(WIX_ROOT)" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: So, the documentation was wrong.  OK.  I ended up with a solution that worked for me without using the ItemGroup, but at least the correct usage is now documented on SO!

Comment: This will cause Visual Studio to throw an error about an invalid paramter unless you add  'InProject' metadata like so:  `<BindInputPaths Include="..."><InProject>false</InProject>
</BindInputPaths>`  see: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19515397/deploy-multiple-wcf-webservices-with-wix-toolset-wrong-svc-files)

Comment: @SteveSheldon, that's not generally true -- it works fine for me as-is today with VS2013, for example. Maybe it's needed for HeatDirectory with named bind paths?

Comment: What if I'd be to use it as msbuild parameters?
At the moment I'm able to use single source directory like so: `/p:LinkerBindInputPaths=$outPath`

What if I'm building 2+ projects to separate directories? Then it would make sense to do either `/p:LinkerBindInputPaths=$outPath1 /p:LinkerBindInputPaths=$outPath2` or something like `/p:LinkerBindInputPaths="$outPath1, $outPath2"` but neither work and I failed to find any documentation on that parameter.